# Form valid check not working after reset in angular 4

Tags: forms, angular2-template, angular4-forms

I have template driven form validation and binding the form's overall validity via the form template reference variable to the button's disabled property using an event binding. And resetting the form with refresh button

```
<button class="btn btn-standard" name="refresh"
            (click)="simpleForm.reset()">Refresh</button>
<button class="btn btn-standard" name="submit" [disabled]="!simpleForm.form.valid" (click)="doAction()">Submit</button>
```

Here, simpleForm.form.valid is working perfectly for the first time, but the problem occurs when we do reset with refresh, after reset form valid is not working. kindly help us with what is missing here

Answer (score 0):

If you're using template driven resetting this shouldn't affect the form validation. However you're using a customer method on submit. Why not use ngSubmit inside the form tag.

Can you post the form tag as well?

Comment: submitting the form is not a problem here, issue is enabling the submit button. we are enabling the submit button only when the form is valid, but after resetting the form on refresh button click and form valid check is not returning true even the form is in valid state.